# Why it's not possible to restore a deleted branch from remote in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, restore

My teammate removed a branch from remote repository. It was easy to fix by using `git reflog`. But I noticed there's no way to do this without having a local copy of branch or reflog.

My question is - what's the reason behind this? Since now all Git design decisions seemed to be reasonable, but I can't really understand this one.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's because you don't just remove the tag of the branch it's because you push an empty branch above the existing one. Check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23961231/2475001

Comment: That explains a lot.
But the next question is - shouldn't git prevent situations like this one? I mean - shouldn't it save all code history, no matter if it was on deleted branch or not?

Comment: Well I guess it should in some way but I think their approach was more "you know what you do so i'll trust you and do what you say". also i think the fact that you keep a local track of everything you've fetched helps, even more with the reflog